# DataGridView trying to parse decimal as Int32

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that is populated from a database. I have a column `Count` that is blank when initially loaded, but I am still binding it to a `NULL` value in the query.

If I enter a numeric value in the `Count` column, it will work fine if the number is an integer, but if I try to enter a decimal then I receive the following error:

> System.FormatException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32. ---> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
>
> at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)

-snip- the rest of the stack trace -snip-

I have tried to set the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` to `N2` as well as `c`, and still receive the error either way. I'm not sure why it is trying to parse the number as an `Int32`, since I am not specifying that anywhere. The only place I am specifying any format is in the `DefaultCellStyle.Format` property. Is there somewhere else that I should be specifying that I *want* to allow a decimal value, and to parse the number as a decimal rather than integer? This project is in VB.NET, but this seems to be related to .NET in general, so advice can be in C# or VB.NET if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out shortly after posting the question. I had to format the `NULL` value I was populating from the database as a `DECIMAL(9, 2)`, and now everything seems to be working. For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(9, 2), NULL) AS [Count]
FROM MyTable
```

Where what I had before was:

```
SELECT NULL AS [Count]
FROM MyTable
```

I thought perhaps that just setting the column formatting in the `DataGridView` would be sufficient, but for some reason it wanted to default to `Int32` for a `NULL` value.